# How to manually install dependencies for a PHP project?

Tags: php, installation, include, meilisearch

I know that I should be using Composer. I've not ventured there just yet.

I want to try [Meilisearch](https://meilisearch.com) Search service, and they have a PHP SDK.

According to the docs of the [PHP SDK](https://github.com/meilisearch/meilisearch-php#-installation):

> To get started, simply require the project using Composer. You will
> also need to install packages that "provide"
> psr/http-client-implementation and psr/http-factory-implementation. A
> list with compatible HTTP clients and client adapters can be found at
> php-http.org.
>
> If you don't know which HTTP client to use, we recommend using [Guzzle 7](https://github.com/php-http/guzzle7-adapter)

So, This is what I've inserted in my php file:

```
include './search/guzzle7/src/Client.php';
include './search/guzzle7/src/Promise.php';
include './search/meilisearchPhp/src/MeiliSearch.php';
include './search/meilisearchPhp/src/Client.php';
```

Given that I get this error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'MeiliSearch\Client' not found

It's pretty clear that I'm adding the files incorrectly. Any advice on this?

The github repos are:
[Meilisearch](https://github.com/meilisearch/MeiliSearch)
[Meilisearch PHP SDK](https://github.com/meilisearch/meilisearch-php)
[Guzzle 7](https://github.com/php-http/guzzle7-adapter)

I have the original Meilisearch project in the same folder as all other projects, the *search* folder (./search/meilisearch/)

Thanks for your help!

Comment: "I know that I should be using Composer. I've not ventured there just yet." <- is there any reason you haven't? I mean, it makes things 10 times easier. You just run one command to install the given package and include a single vendor/autoload.php file, then everything just works.

Comment: Just use composer

Comment: I think you're right... every time I need to install something is a pain in the backteeth :)

Comment: Hey @Rosamunda I made a issue on the PHP client of MeilISearch: https://github.com/meilisearch/meilisearch-php/issues/107 feel free to give your opinion